# What's the C# syntax for using a Border control with rounded corners in dotnet Maui?

Tags: c#, maui

Can anyone suggest the correct C# syntax for wrapping a view with a `Border` that has rounded corners?

I've found lots of examples using XAML, but I can't find any C# examples and can't figure out how to do the same in C# (I'm new to Maui and C#).

For example, how would I add rounded corners to the following?

```
new Border()
{
    new VerticalStackLayout()
    {
        ...
    }
}
.StrokeShape(...what goes here?...)
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign a [RoundRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.shapes.roundrectangle?view=net-maui-7.0) to your StrokeShape. Here's an example, based on [the example in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border?view=net-maui-7.0):

```
Border myBorder = new Border
{
    StrokeThickness = 4,
    ...
    StrokeShape = new RoundRectangle
    {
        CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(40, 0, 0, 40)
    },
    ...
    Content = new VerticalStackLayout
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

This example creates a border where two of the four corners are rounded. If you want all corners to be (uniformly) rounded, just use the `CornerRadius` constructor that takes only a single parameter.